# Can use of $regex in MongoDB Aggregation Framework be optimized?

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently using the Aggregation Framework to calculate some aggregate values on a collection.  The typical query/operation might include close to 1 million documents that are indexed (the f1/ts match reduces the number of documents down to the 1 million from about 5 million, the set can be made smaller depending on the query parameters, e.g. timeframe selected).

The **$match** uses indexed attributes of the documents, but I need to include what amounts to a full-text search.  The only option that I've used is a **$regex** match.  Unfortunately, I can't anchor my **$regex** match to the start of the string since the string(s) I'm looking could be anywhere.  The text I'm "searching" could be anywhere from a few characters in length to a few thousand.

Just running some basic comparisons, the inclusion of the **$regex** match attribute nearly doubles the time the calculation takes to complete.

- What are my options for optimizing this operation?
- Is it possible to achieve this some other way?
- Will text-search be available for use in aggregation operations in v2.6?

For reference:

**Operation without $regex**

```
db.my_collection.aggregate(
 {
   $match:{
     f1:ObjectId('417abd81...577000006'),
     ts:{$gte:t1,$lte:t2}
   }
 },{
   $project:{
     ts:1,
     p:1
   }
 },{
   $group:{
     _id:"$ts",
     x: {
       $sum:"$p"
     }
   }
 });
```

**Operation with $regex**

```
db.my_collection.aggregate(
 {
   $match:{
     f1:ObjectId('417abd81...577000006'),
     ts:{$gte:t1,$lte:t2}
   }
 },
 {
   $match:{
     c:{$regex: /somevalue/i}
   }
 },{
   $project:{
     ts:1,
     p:1
   }
 },{
   $group:{
     _id:"$ts",
     x: {
       $sum:"$p"
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need to switch your search to a different engine like ElasticSearch or Solr? It's difficult to optimize a brute force $regex like that.

Comment: And no, it doesn't seem likely that full text search will be included in the Aggregation framework, especially given how it's used. There's no mention of it in the release notes for 2.6 either (Development series 2.5).

Comment: Would your suggestion be to switch to ElasticSearch - I need to do what is really an exact keyword match (no stemming, etc.) - to collect the _id values of the items I need to aggregate?  And then pass the array of _id values (potentially tens of thousands) to the aggregation call?